# How to use a jQuery plugin with underscore.js template

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jquery-plugins, underscore.js

I need to validate a form using `jquery.validator` plugin. I am using `backbone.js` which utilizes an `underscore.js template` for the form. So where do I add the jQuery Validate script; in `somethingTemplate.html` or some other file?

Comment: http://blog.leshill.org/blog/2011/08/14/jquery-validation-plugin-and-backbone.html

Comment: I went through your blog previously but still couldn't figure it out. Do I add validation rules at Backbone.view page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"On submit" type validation:
 1. Instantiate the script in your view
 2. Build your form using view and template -- don't forget validation tags as defined in documentation
 3. Catch form submit in view event
 4. `event.preventDefault()`
 5. Validate using validator API -- .valid() method
 6. Submit on success

"Live" type validation:
 1. Instantiate script in your view
 2. Build form with valid "validate" tags in html
 3. In view, call validate script, `$("#form").validate();`

Using the live method, the submit button will remain disabled until form is fully validated.  It can be a good or bad method, depending on your interface and form specifics.

Don't forget that front-end (javascript) validation is no replacement for proper back-end validation!